# Html.BeginForm with rich text editor inside

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, razor

I am struggling with a partialview with a form inside it. Normally when I post it and it has validation errors, it doesn't call the actual `[httppost]` actionresult.

Now I am using Yahoo Rich Text Editor, which uses JavaScript to create.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NieuwBericht","Bericht"))
{@Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    <div class="center">

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Onderwerp)
    <div class="yui-skin-sam">

    <div>

    @Html.TextAreaFor(p => Model.Inhoud, new { @id = "msgpost", @cols = "50", @rows = "20" })
    </div>

    <div class="berichthead">Naar: @Html.EditorFor(p => Model.Ontvangers)
    Onderwerp: @Html.EditorFor(p => Model.Onderwerp) 
    <input style="float: right;" class="button" type="submit" />

    </div>

     </div>

    </div>       
}

@Html.TextAreaFor(p => Model.Inhoud, new { @id = "msgpost", @cols = "50", @rows = "20" })
```

This part is rendered with JavaScript. When this is inside my form, the form first returns itself with the validation errors, and after that it calls the httppost method and recreates the partial again with the same model.

I want the partial to stay on the same page and just return the form with the validation errors. Is this possible with a JavaScript part inside it? Because this causes to call the actionresult somehow.

I used some js on other forms aswell for datepicker etc, there it doesn't cause any trouble. (This one never calls the actionresult if there are validation errors)